# How to set firefox full screen with addon SDK (no html5 api)?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, gecko

How to set firefox full screen with addon SDK (no html5 api)?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you ask the <kbd>F11</kbd> version of full screen.

```js
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');

getMostRecentBrowserWindow().BrowserFullScreen();
```